# Crystax NDK visual studio 2015

Tags: android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

Приложение под андроид. Пытаюсь запустить `nativeActivity` с использованием *Crystax ndk* - замена стандартному гугловскому. Вылетает ошибка типа:

> cannot find -lcrystax

Нашел, что это связано с линковкой, и можно прилинковать статически, но в 2015 студии я не могу найти настроек как тут:

- ```
  Added "copy /b /y 
  $(VS_NdkRoot)\sources\crystax\libs\$(TargetArchAbi)\libcrystax.a 
  $(TargetDir)" to Pre-Link Event: http://prntscr.com/9kfo4y
  ```
- ```
  Added "$(TargetDir)" to Additional Library Directories: 
  http://prntscr.com/9kfoyb
  ```

Как же быть с студией 2015?

Answer (score 1):

Всё нашел! В обозревателе решений, в свойствах активити. Спасибо